# Why is the first iterator in frames in FuncAnimation repeated?

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

I am running a simple test on FuncAnimation when I noticed that the first index in frames is being repeated. This is the code that I have:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig = plt.figure( figsize=(10,6) ) 
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

Writer = animation.writers['ffmpeg']
writer = Writer(fps=20, metadata=dict(artist='Me'))

def animate(i):
    x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 120)
    y = np.cos(i*x)
    z = x 
    ax.clear()
    print(i)
    im = ax.plot(x, y, z)

ani = matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=range(5), repeat=False, blit=False)
ani.save("movie.mp4", writer=writer)
plt.show()
```

When I run this, I get the following output:

```
0
0
1
2
3
4
```

What I do not understand is why are the 0's showing up twice in the output?

Answer (score 3):

The reason is, that You are not passing `init_func` attribute into `FuncAnimation`.
This quote from [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation.html) explains why:

> init_func : callable, optional
> A function used to draw a clear frame. If not given, the results of
> drawing from the first item in the frames sequence will be used. This
> function will be called once before the first frame.

So when You start Your animation, first frame is always drawn as a result of `init_func`. You can set custom `init_func`, which is called in the beginning of animation instead.